# MySQL: Alter table to set Foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

Although there are some similar questions about the subject, I can't find the right answer for my problem. I have 2 tables called `customer` and `car`. What I want to do is this: When I delete a customer from database, I want the car that belongs to that customer will be automatically deleted as well. The code that MySQL Workbench generated for me is this:

```
ALTER TABLE `autocare`.`car` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `customerId`
FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`)
REFERENCES `autocare`.`customer` (`ID`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`autocare`.`#sql-80c_388`, CONSTRAINT `customerId` FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`)
REFERENCES `customer` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

There was no relation between those tables before. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is likely that there exists a `car.CUSTOMER_ID` which does not have a matching parent row in `customer.ID`. When you try to add the key constraint, rows which don't match an existing parent cause the constraint to fail.

Comment: Find them with something like `SELECT * FROM car WHERE CUSTOMER_ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM customer)`

Comment: I see. Is there any easy way to reset all records id numbers in both table? I have 50 rows in both table.

Comment: You can't modify `customer.ID` without breaking existing relationships in the child table. If your goal is to cascade deletion, first identify the orphan records in `car` and just delete them, then add the FK constraint.

Comment: I got it! If you answer the question I can mark it as the right answer. Thank you for your help @MichaelBerkowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is ultimately to implement a cascading deletion from `customer` to `car`.  When you attempt to add the constraint with the tables as they are now, it fails because the `car` table must include rows having a a `CUSTOMER_ID` value which does not currently exist in the parent `customer` table.

You should first locate those orphan rows and delete them (since your goal is to delete them anyway). You can find them with a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM car
WHERE
 CUSTOMER_ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM customer)
```

Once the orphan records are removed, the foreign key constraint can be met by the remaining existing rows and your `ALTER TABLE` statement will succeed.